# Android WebView scale misbehaving

Tags: android, webview

I am facing a strange issue with `WebView` in Android. I wrote a sample application which displays some test message using `WebView`. The Application has two activities, one activity simply contains a button: when user clicks on this button, it launches another activity which displays the test message on a `WebView`.

I have set `setInitialScale()` of `WebView` as 150, and made `setLoadWithOverviewMode()` and `setUseWideViewPort()` as `false`.

Now the issue is like, normally `WebView` displays the content with the scale size 150 (as I set in my app) but sometimes it displays the contents with a scale greater than 150. I am wondering why this is happening!

I did some investigation on this and my observations are given below:

I overrided the `onScaleChanged()` function in `webViewClient`. In normal case before drawing the content on `WebView`, I am getting `onScaleChanged()` callback with the values  `[ oldScale : 2 and newScale 1.5]`.

When the issue occurs, I am getting two `onScaleChanged()` callbacks before drawing the content! At first, I get the `onScalechange()` callback with values  `[ oldScale : 2 and newScale 1.5]`, just after that getting another `onScaleChanged()` callback with values `[ oldScale : 1.5 and newScale 2.0]` and hence it draws the `WebView` with the scale 2.0 irrespective of `setInitialScale()` I have given in my application.

This issue happens only in the case if I set `setInitialScale()` to a value less than device's default `WebView` scale.

As per my understanding, every device has its own default scale for `webview` based on their display property (like, 0.75 for ldpi and 1.5 for hdpi, etc.)

In my device, `defaultScale` for `webview` is 2, and I set the `setInitialScale()` as 1.5(150). Normally `WebView` resets the scale from 2 to 1.5 before drawing (that is from default to new value) and it works fine. But sometime after changing the scale to 1.5, it is reverting back to 2, and the issue occurs.

I am pasting my sample code here, why it is happening? Is it because of any implementation issue in my code? Or is it the behaviour/bug/limitation of Android? I have tested this in Android 4.2.

```
public class webActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);
        WebView webview= (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webview.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
        webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(false);
        webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);
        webview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
        webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
        webview.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
        webview.setInitialScale(150);
        //test message 
        String html = "<html><body>test meassage test message test message test message test message</body></html>";
        String mime = "text/html";
        String encoding = "utf-8";
      //  myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, html, mime, encoding, null);          
    }   
    public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
    {

        @Override
        public void onScaleChanged(WebView view, float oldScale, float newScale) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.e("WEBVIEW ","  >>>>>>>> ScaleChanged OldScale" +oldScale +"  New Scale :"+newScale);
            super.onScaleChanged(view, oldScale, newScale);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;

        }
    }

}
```

## Layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```